# Why is my PHP code not deleting a row in database?

Tags: php, mysql

The code below should be able to delete a row from table `car` having `ProNumber='$searchTerm'` and  `ProCode ='$searchTerm1'` but it is not.Any help will be much appreciated .

```
<?php
$searchTerm = trim($_GET['keyname']);
$searchTerm1 = trim($_GET['codename']);
//create a database connection
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error:".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("products");
//Delete the record
$updateQuery = "DELETE FROM car WHERE ProNumber = '$searchTerm' AND ProCode ='$searchTerm1'";
mysql_query($updateQuery) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
?>
```

note that the table and columns are created and filled with the corespondent data.
**Update :**
The following part of the answer to this question is what solved it 
**Mysql vs Mysqli Functions**

mysql_* functions are deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 you should use the mysqli_* functions to make sure your scripts works on newer PHP Versions.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli).

Comment: What BlueDog said, also show sample data

Comment: Are ProCode and ProNumber integers in your database?

Comment: How are you executing this script? Is the URL ending with `?keyname=…&codename=…`?

Comment: i wonder why i was down voted :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Column Types**

please make sure that your column types are correct. if you wrap your data into quotes like this `'1234'` mysql will interpret the data as a `string`, write it without quotes and it will be interpreted as an `integer`.

`WHERE column = 1234` on `integer` columns
`WHERE column = '1234'` on `varchar` columns

**SQL Injections**

please use before pass variables directly into sql statements teh php `mysqli_real_escape_string` function, to prevent `SQL Injections`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

**Mysql vs Mysqli Functions**

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated in PHP `5.5.0` you should use the `mysqli_*` functions to make sure your scripts works on newer PHP Versions.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

**Logical Error**

Make sure data you want to delete is present in your Mysql Database

Comment: thanks for the help mate , i changed code to mysqli and checked data types it works !!! Thanks again

Comment: Or just use prepared statements instead of mysqli_real_escape_string() and you should be safe against sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Error is in your database connection , you cannot delete records until your database connection is not set

```
//create a database connection
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error:".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("products");

Change above code to this 

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error:".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("products",$connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but one problem you might have is that you have single quotes around `$searchTerm`. Your searching for a number but your passing a string.

Possible fix (Notice the single quotes are missing from `$searchTerm`):

```
$updateQuery = "DELETE FROM car WHERE ProNumber = $searchTerm AND ProCode = '$searchTerm1'";
```

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '¨' at line 1

Comment: Can you share your table definition? What are the data types of ProNumber and ProCode?

Comment: ProNumber int(6) and ProCode varchar(2)

Comment: What kind of value does $searchTerm1 hold? Two character string?